# Animate div then fade out another div

Tags: jquery

```
$('li:not(#blob)', nav).hover(function() {
    // mouse over
    clearTimeout(reset);

    blob.animate(
        {
            left : $(this).position().left,
            width : $(this).width()


        },
        {
            duration : options.speed,
            easing : options.easing,
            queue : false
        },
         function(){
         $('#slate').fadeOut('fast', function(){ 
         $('#slate').html($('.stuff1').html()).fadeIn('fast');
                 }); 
                } 
         );                                          
       });
```

I been trying to get a div (not connected to the animation) to fade out, get the contents of a hidden div (which is nested inside the li element which "blob" has moved to) after the animation happens, I think I'm going in the right direction here but can't seem to get this to work properly.

Being a jQuery novice I can't understand why a callback is not being made after the animate function?

Edit:

below I have posted the full function I am trying to doctor. I trying to get the function to fade out change the content to the content of a div that is nested in each of the li's. at the moment I using content from just one of them on a I will cross that bridge when I come to it basis.

The function moves the blob element to the li element the cursor is hovering over.

js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CK2pZ/4/

```
jQuery(function($) {

$.fn.spasticNav = function(options) {

    options = $.extend({
        overlap : 0,
        speed : 500,
        reset : 1500,
        color : '#0b2b61',
        easing : 'easeOutExpo'
    }, options);

    return this.each(function() {

        var nav = $(this),
            currentPageItem = $('#selected', nav),
            blob,
            reset;

        $('<li id="blob"></li>').css({
            width : currentPageItem.outerWidth(),
            height : currentPageItem.outerHeight() + options.overlap,
            left : currentPageItem.position().left,
            top : currentPageItem.position().top - options.overlap / 2,
            backgroundColor : options.color
        }).appendTo(this);


        blob = $('#blob', nav);

        $('li:not(#blob)', nav).hover(function() {
            // mouse over
            clearTimeout(reset);

            blob.animate(
                {
                    left : $(this).position().left,
                    width : $(this).width()


                },
                {
                    duration : options.speed,
                    easing : options.easing,
                    queue : false
                },
                                    function(){
                                     $('#slate').fadeOut('fast', function(){ 
                                     $('#slate').html($('.stuff1').html()).fadeIn('fast');
                                     }); 
                        } 
                               );



                     });


    }); // end each



};


})(jQuery);
```

Comment: if slate is not visible, the stuff inside it will also not be visible

Comment: JSfiddle what you've got...

Comment: @smerny who said it's not visible?

Comment: `fadeOut` says its not visible... ah, it appears i missed an end para and that the `fadeIn` is on `slate` rather than its content

Comment: I have put a jsfiddle up here http://jsfiddle.net/CK2pZ/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified many things in your jsfiddle just to get it to work, including `onload` so that the js could access the DOM. In your code you'll have to make sure the js is within a `$(document).ready()`... after that I made a few changes:

- add "blobbed" class to first li in #nav
  `$(this).children().first().addClass("blobbed");`
- when event is triggered, change the blobbed class to be only on the li that triggered the event
  `$('li').removeClass("blobbed");

  $(this).addClass("blobbed");`
- put your animations within this conditional:
  `if(!$(this).hasClass("blobbed"))`
- unwrapped the `fadeOut` stuff
- used `$('li:not(#blob)', nav).on("mouseover", function () {..` instead of `$('li:not(#blob)', nav).hover(function () {`

Check here for details and to see it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/fWP5u/2/

Comment: This sort of works, I kind of had it working like this before. But every time you move over the selected li element the div fades ans fades back again. This is why I was trying to tag it on to the animate.

Comment: Thank you smerny, you are a genius. Reckon you've saved me a week of my life :-) BTW. Sorry it was my first ever jsfiddle.